# jQuery get text include single quote using text() doesn't show properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want to show div's text to input value if button clicked. But if the text includes single quote, It doesn't show properly.

```
<div id="content_comment">It's Yours!</div>
<button id="btn_comment_edit">Edit</button>     

// jQuery
$('.btn_comment_edit').click(function(){
    $('#content_comment').replaceWith("<form method='post'><input type=text value='"+$('#content_comment').text()+"'></form>")
});

// result 
// It'  (doesn't show after single quotes)
```

It should be `It's Yours!` in input value. How can I display whole statement with single quotes?

Comment: try to use removing the ' from the text, or encode it somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the usages of single and double quotes. You are also using `.btn_comment_edit` instead of `#btn_comment_edit`. Try like following.

```js
$('#btn_comment_edit').click(function () {
    $('#content_comment').replaceWith('<form method=post><input type=text value="' + $('#content_comment').text() + '"></form>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content_comment">It's Yours!</div>
<button id="btn_comment_edit">Edit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
 $('#content_comment').replaceWith("<form method='post'><input type=text value='\'' +$('#content_comment').text()+'\'></form>")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do the encoding.

```
$('.btn_comment_edit').click(function(){        
    var a = $('#content_comment').text();
    a = addslash(a);           
    $('#content_comment').replaceWith("<form method='post'><input type=text value='"+a+"'></form>")
});

function addslash(iid){
    str=iid.replace(/"/g,'\"');
    str=iid.replace(/'/g,'\'');
    return str;
}
```